# Why am I getting this error on a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, gack

How can I tell what error I have?

> System.UnexpectedException: Internal Salesforce Error: 224634669-218106 (-854602049) (-854602049) 
>   Stack Trace: External entry point Class.CandidatesTabsTest.testMyController: line 185, column 1

Comment: You can actually usually divine (approximately) the cause of a given gack by checking the logs. Run the unit test, then go to the Logs tab in the Developer Console and read the last few lines. Usually, you'll see line numbers leading up to the internal server error. If you post some code and the few lines of logs leading up to the error, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 10):

That is a GACK response. See [What Is A Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)

> A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
>
> What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!

Basically, something broke internally within Salesforce and the only thing to come out to you is the GACK error code.

You will need to examine what that test class is doing to try and isolate the problem. Raising a support case is also an option as they can tell you what caused the underling fault.

If you find raising a support case to get the GACK details, er, *challenging*, please consider voting for the idea:

> ## [Provide a public reference of GACK general stack trace identifiers](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DklZAAS)
>
> As per [What Is A Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html), the number in the parentheses of a GACK Error Id is the general stack trace id.
>
> This represents the common stack trace for a specific internal error.
>
> Create a system that exposes limited information about that general error that will be useful to users. Users could be directed there directly from the GACK error page.
>
> E.g.
>
> - Is there a fix scheduled in the next release for that error
> - What are the common causes of the error and work arounds
> - If it is reproducable by Salesforce (I.e. should you go to the effort of telling Salesforce how it occured)
>
> Ideally this will remove the need to contact support to determine what went wrong until the internal fix is deployed. Especially if they already know what is going wrong or have already fixed it for the next release.
>
> It might be tied into the [known issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index) system.

Comment: Ha, "they can tell you what caused the underling fault" - **only if** you make it past tier 1 and the closing of the case as being out of scope or being told that they have no way to look up the information.....

Comment: @Eric Well, yes. It is a somewhat optimistic statement. On a good day it is a viable option, especially if you have access to premiere support. Otherwise, yeah, it might just be more frustrating to try and raise a support case than just find the cause yourself.

Comment: Yea, I got a good chuckle out of it though.

Comment: @Eric Votes appreciated on the now linked idea for a public GACK reference.

Comment: I actually kind of missed that you even linked to an idea until reading that comment. I edited your post to make it a little more obvious (and hopefully get more votes!).